# Reading a CSV files using Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm reading a csv file. I am using Akka Streams to do this so that I can create a graph of actions to perform on each line. I've got the following toy example up and running.

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem("MyAkkaSystem")
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

        val source = akka.stream.scaladsl.Source.fromIterator(Source.fromFile("a.csv").getLines)
        val sink = Sink.foreach(println)
        source.runWith(sink)
      }
```

The two `Source` types don't sit easy with me. Is this idiomatic or is there is a better way to write this?

Answer (score 23):

Actually, `akka-streams` provides a function to directly read from a file.

```
FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("a.csv"))
      .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 256, true).map(_.utf8String))
      .runForeach(println)
```

Here, `runForeach` method is to print the lines. If you have a proper `Sink` to process these lines, use it instead of this function. For example, if you want to split the lines by `'` and print the total number of words in it:

```
val sink: Sink[String] = Sink.foreach(x => println(x.split(",").size))

FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("a.csv"))
      .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 256, true).map(_.utf8String))
      .to(sink)
      .run()
```

Comment: Yeah I came across this the other day. I will probably use it. I tried using the PureCSV library but it loads all the file in memory before processing which defeats the purpose of using a stream based approach.

Answer (score 16):

The idiomatic way to read a CSV file with Akka Streams is to use the [Alpakka CSV connector](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/0.18/data-transformations/csv.html). The following example reads a CSV file, converts it to a map of column names (assumed to be the first line in the file) and `ByteString` values, transforms the `ByteString` values to `String` values, and prints each line:

```
FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("a.csv"))
  .via(CsvParsing.lineScanner())
  .via(CsvToMap.toMap())
  .map(_.mapValues(_.utf8String))
  .runForeach(println)
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
import java.nio.file.Paths

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.util.ByteString

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object ReadStreamApp extends App {
  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
  import actorSystem.dispatcher
  implicit val flowMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val logFile = Paths.get("src/main/resources/a.csv")

  val source = FileIO.fromPath(logFile)

  val flow = Framing
    .delimiter(ByteString(System.lineSeparator()), maximumFrameLength = 512, allowTruncation = true)
    .map(_.utf8String)

  val sink = Sink.foreach(println)

  source
    .via(flow)
    .runWith(sink)
    .andThen {
      case _ =>
        actorSystem.terminate()
        Await.ready(actorSystem.whenTerminated, 1 minute)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it's ok because these are different `Source`s. But if you don't like `scala.io.Source` you can read file yourself (which sometimes we have to do e.g. source `csv` file is zipped) and then parse it using given `InputStream` like this

```
StreamConverters.fromInputStream(() => input)
  .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 4096))
  .map(_.utf8String)
  .collect { line =>
    line
  }
```

Having said that consider using `Apache Commons CSV` with akka-stream. You may end up writing less code :)

Comment: Hi, I was trying to run this example for a few minutes, I didn't succeeded (implicits and all). Can I ask you please to provide missing imports and setup?