# Akka stream: process CSV with header

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

[Reading a CSV files using Akka Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224457/reading-a-csv-files-using-akka-streams)
- based on this question.
I have CSV read using Akka Streams.
Now I need to perform process it line by line - but I also need to know what were the names of headers.
Any options?

UPD.
Clarifying a bit.

```
FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("a.csv))
.via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 256, true).map(_.utf8String))
.runForeach(println /* header  + current line for each line*/)
```

Comment: Won't the headers be in the first line of your CSV? Could you add more details about the concrete problem you're facing?

Comment: added sample of what I need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`prefixAndTail`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#prefixAndTail) to take the first element - in this case the headers - and then combine it lazily with subsequent elements (the rows).

Here's an example with the headers and columns combined to form a `Map[String, String]`:

```
val flow: Flow[Seq[String], Map[String, String], NotUsed] = Flow[Seq[String]]
  .prefixAndTail(1).flatMapConcat { case (headers, rows) =>
    rows.map (row => headers.head.zip(row).toMap)
  }

val test: Source[Seq[String], NotUsed] = Source(
  List(Seq("col1", "col2"), Seq("a", "b"), Seq("1", "2")))

Await.result(test.via(flow).runForeach(println), 20.seconds)
// Map(col1 -> a, col2 -> b)
// Map(col1 -> 1, col2 -> 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Alpakka, the collection of Akka Streams connectors, provides [CSV support](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/0.17/data-transformations/csv.html):

```
Source
  .single(ByteString("""header1,header2,header3
                       |1,2,3
                       |4,5,6""".stripMargin))
  .via(CsvParsing.lineScanner())
  .via(CsvToMap.toMap())
  .map(_.mapValues(_.utf8String))
  .runForeach(println)

// Map(header1 -> 1, header2 -> 2, header3 -> 3)
// Map(header1 -> 4, header2 -> 5, header3 -> 6)
```

Comment: This library is fantastic.

Comment: but i would you write a csv file with its header then : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62824629/how-to-write-csv-file-with-headers-using-akka-stream-alpakka ?

Comment: I have that code that you have above but can't figure how to write it back after filtering some row